# Difference between Drill Through and Linked Reports in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Could anybody explain me the difference between Linked reports and drill through reports in ssrs (version 2012)..

Been through several videos and a bit confused as in terms of functionality both look similar...linking one report to the other(parent-child) by passing a parameter from one to the other..

So what's the difference.. whether or not functionality-wise or just in terms of a business requirement..?

Comment: "Linked report is like virtual copy of original report to which you can pass different parameter and you can create different subscription. but report design and connection will be similar to original.

In drill through report when you click on some values in table or matrix you are passing values from one report to another and on the bases of these parameter new report having some data filtered and displayed in it." https://www.codeproject.com/questions/799424/difference-between-linked-report-and-drill-through

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Drill Through Reports:** The word "drill-through" indicates that we can drill into a specific value on one report for getting additional information from another report. For example, consider a scenario where you have two reports like Orders and Order Details. The Orders report has a list of all orders with OrderIDs and the OrderItems report is a separate report which displays the details of an orderID which is passed as a parameter to the report. You can set up these reports in such a way that when you click on the OrderID value of the Orders report, you can pass this ID value to OrderDetails and open this report to see the details of this order. 
This is how drill-through report work. The two report can be different or same reports and they are not dependent on each other.

**Linked Reports:** Linked reports are usually created from a report manager only. Linked reports are not developed from BIDS or Visual Studio. Hence, they do not have a .rdl file. Linked reports are usually created from a parent/base report. The base report may have multiple parameters. When you create a linked report, you can create a separate report from the base report with fixed parameter values.When you make changes on the report design on the base report, the same changes are automatically applied to the linked reports also.